Updating wp-config.php but it doesnt seem to exist
There doesn't appear to be a wp-config.php file in the root folder of my wp install. There is one in the file directory up but it doesn't provide any of the usual details, it only shows as per the below:
<?php
/**
 * Do not edit this file. Edit the config files found in the config/ dir instead.
 * This file is required in the root directory so WordPress can find it.
 * WP is hardcoded to look in its own directory or one directory up for wp-config.php.
 */
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/application.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');"



There is one in the file directory up

That is your wp-config.php, WordPress can look one folder up so that you can place the file in a folder that's not served to the web. This is done as a security measure.

it doesn't provide any of the usual details

wp-config.php is still a PHP file, as long as loading that file defines what's needed you don't need to do it the normal way. Your wp-config.php could bootstrap a whole other CMS and query it for the database details/login/prefix/etc, or fire a remote request!
On some of the sites I work with, the constants are placed in individual files so that I can conditionally load them based on the environment, e.g. wp-local-config.php might be loaded for local development, but not on the production server, providing different DB details and constants.
Instead it looks like your wp-config.php does 3 things:

Load the Composer autoloader for Composer packages and other stuff in the vendor folder
Load a config/application.php that takes care of all the constants such as DB host etc
Loads wp-settings.php as all wp-config.php files are supposed to do


Thank you for your reply, I really appreciate it. I need to add some code in relation to the SSL cert, am I ok to add it to the wp-config.php file I have even though it explicitly tells me not to edit it? Alternatively could I add a new wp-config.php in the wp root or would that mess with my current setup? Thanks again in advance.

The comment that tells you not to edit it also tells you where to go instead. It both tells you what to do and what not to do, anything i tell you is just that comment rephrased in different words. Just trust it, whoever set this up for you set things up that way. Messing around and modifying a file they told you not to modify might interfere with that. Without everyone seeing the contents of that file and any files it includes it's not possible to give you reassurance ( and sharing those files would be a massive security breach )

A very quick github code search for the phrase WP is hardcoded to look in its own directory or one directory up for wp-config.php. that is in the comment brings up lots of results heavily implying that this WordPress install is setup with Bedrock and that if you want a good answer you'll need to look at the Bedrock docs or ask other users of Bedrock in their community
